# Accurately track users rotation in degrees around an object using Core Motion

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-motion

I'm currently trying to accurately track a users movement in degrees around an object like a car for example.

The user will have his iPhone in landscape orientation as he moves around the car. I want to capture a photo for every degree the user has rotated around the car.

I'm currently using `CoreMotion` to try and determine the `Yaw`.

```
let queue = OperationQueue.main
motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1 / 30
motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(using: .xArbitraryZVertical, to: queue) { (motion, error) in
  if let deviceMotion = motion {
    let quat = deviceMotion.attitude.quaternion

    let ysqr = quat.y * quat.y
    let t3 = 2.0 * (quat.w * quat.z + quat.x * quat.y)
    let t4 = 1.0 - 2.0 * (ysqr + quat.z * quat.z)
    let yaw = atan2(t3, t4)

    print(round(self.degrees(yaw)))
  }
}
```

I've noticed that when I'm moving around the object that the `Yaw` is affected when the device `Pitch` or `Roll` changes.

Is there anyway I can accurately track the `Yaw` in a 360 degree rotation around an object?

Comment: `attitude` has built in properties of `pitch`, `roll`, and `yaw`. Why are you trying to calculate these yourself?

Comment: I was trying to use a `Quaternion` as I noticed that my `yaw` changes when `roll` or `pitch` changes. I need to just accurately track the 360 degree rotation around an object.

Comment: What you probably want in this case is none of `pitch`, `roll` or `yaw` but actually the "compass" direction of the device. It will change more like you want it to change and not be affected by moving in other directions. You should also be able to get that from the device motion.

Comment: @Fogmeister Thank you for the feedback. I will have to read up on that as I have no idea on how to get the "compass" direction using `CoreMotion`.

Comment: Having a look, you'll need `CoreLocation` to get the heading not `CoreMotion`.  But it works very much the same way and uses a combination of magnetometers and device motion to detect the heading. Take a look at `CLLocationManager` and `startUpdatingHeading`. I have used this to create a "Direction pointer" in an app in the past and it updates very quickly.

Comment: @Fogmeister Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. This seems to be the solution for what I want to achieve. I will read through the docs for `CLLocationManager` and `startUpdatingHeading`.

Comment: No worries, :D Glad to help. Added it as an answer.

Comment: @martisan How can you capture 360 image with user rotation ? can you please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want to be looking at is using `CoreLocation` (specifically `CLLocationManager` and `startUpdatingHeading`) to get the heading of the device.

It is much more reliable at getting the currently heading of the device and updates very quickly.